# What is the index in the select_linked_pick command?

Tags: python, scripting

What is the index argument in the command:

```
bpy.ops.mesh.select_linked_pick(deselect=False, delimit={'SEAM'}, index=1729)
```

Is it possible to find it with python ?

Comment: it's the edge index,and yes you can find it but how exactly you want to find it in python

Comment: This command line was run on a basic UV Sphere and this sphere was not as many edges. Is that there are different index ?

Comment: sorry I didn't understand your comment, but if you could describe what you are trying to accomplish we may find the answer

Comment: Sorry for my late answer. I finally found a solution without using this operator but, i'd ever like to know where this index come from.

Comment: For exemple, if i display the edges index of an selected face, i have these four edge index : 552, 540, 511 and 555. The face index is 255. Now, if i use the select_lincked_pick operator, The index in the operator is 1729. So , where does this index come from if it is that of an edge ?

Comment: it came from you cursor ( mouse ) position on the 3d view, not the selection you made

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the operator `bpy.ops.mesh.select_linked_pick(deselect=False, delimit={'SEAM'}, index=1729)`  the index is taken from the closest element to the mouse cursor and it is calculated as follows :

- For Vertices : `index = vertex.index`.
- For Edges    : `index = len(vertices)+ edge.index`.
- for Faces    :  index = `len(vertices)+ len(edges) + face.index`